# Is there a more user friendly way to figure out where your question fits?

Tags: discussion, usability

I often find it intimidating to try and figure out where my question fits.

And will often end up posting in the wrong spot. Then I will get sent links to meta sites with large amounts of text, explaining why my question does not live there. These meta sites do great work in setting out clear rules, but there is a large amount of information to process.

I fully support the need to maintain the quality of these sites. But I find the user experience is a little lacking.

Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: This has been answered as an aggregate question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390906/where-do-i-go-to-figure-out-in-which-stack-exchange-site-i-can-post-my-question

If you know how to make this a new answer which will be better than any of the answers to the individual two questions, please do so. I don't have time to figure it out. My new answer was automatically converted to a comment. 

Thank you.

Todd B

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If browsing https://stackexchange.com/sites doesn't help, you could always ask here on *Meta Stack Exchange* and tag your question with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

> With the vast openness of the Stack Exchange Network, it can sometimes be confusing where exactly a question is supposed to go. If you are unsure after reading site FAQs, or if you cannot find an existing question here on Meta, consider asking a new question with this tag.
>
> Keep in mind:
>
> - Give an example question you want to ask. If you're going to be vague, it's not going to be the best advice and you may find yourself in rough seas.
> - Not all questions belong on a Q&A site and not everything can find a home here at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Obvious reminder: search specific terms over all sites - field on top of https://stackexchange.com/sites# is the fastest way to check which site has the majority of related questions.