# Is there a way to list all the used tags through all the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, tags, search, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

There is a big number of Stack Exchange sites, so much so that sometimes it's difficult to choose the more appropriate site for our questions. Sometimes there is more than a site that fits to our question. For example, when I have a question about a engineering problem governing by a differential equation and that I want to solve with a computer algebra system implemented in a library in python lenguage. That type of question covers several subjects and it's complicated to choose 1 site for that question. 
I was search about how I can find the Stack Exchange site which fit to my question, and I found the next question:

[Is there a more user friendly way to figure out where your question fits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242409/is-there-a-more-user-friendly-way-to-figure-out-where-your-question-fits)

[How do I determine the best Stack Exchange site for my question before posting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280847/how-do-i-determine-the-best-stack-exchange-site-for-my-question-before-posting)

After read that question, I consider that searching the site's tags and reading their tag wikis and to see the frequency of the use of the tag helps a lot to know if my question fits to the site. But search the tags through the all possible sites is a hard work, so I would like to know if exist a way to list all the tags used throught all the Stack Exchange sites. This will help us to find a specific tag that fits to my question and then to find which SE site this tag belong to.

Is there a way to list all the used tags through all the Stack Exchange sites? or is there a webpage that contain that list of all tags of all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Tags don't mean the same thing on different sites. I can imagine [biology.stackexchange.com](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) having a python tag but it wouldn't mean you can ask your python library question there.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Because that I think that the list must have 2 columns, the first one will contain the tags and the next one the SE sites that contain the tag with its respective frequency of use of the tag.  A good example where we have that problem is the StackOverFlow. It is the most popular site and it has very tags name that are present in other SE sites, then sometime is very ask a question in SO that in other more specific SE site due the low engagement of the member of the specific SE site about a defined topic(tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/724487/tagfinder-network-wide) query for the task.

It finds all tags (and tag synonyms) on all sites matching a given substring, and shows them by decreasing of their relevance:

[image]

It shows also the synonyms.

The "PctOfQuestions" column shows, what percent of the questions are tagged.

It creates also links for the given sites, and for the tags.

A query lasts roughly 10-20 seconds.

It is practical to register on the https://data.stackexchange.com, there you can bookmark it.