# Where does this "environment\recycling" question belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not sure where (if anywhere) my question belongs, so after reading [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242409/is-there-a-more-user-friendly-way-to-figure-out-where-your-question-fits) on Meta SE and browsing through the list of SE sites, I've decided to post it here in order to avoid posting it on the wrong site.

> Assuming barbers throw away all the hair that accumulates on their floor as a result of their work, is the hair just discarded same as any other material to be treated as regular garbage, or are there any technological processes\efforts to recycle it and use it as fuel or precursor for certain industrial processes, on account that it is an entirely biological material?

My question may fit on Biology or Chemistry.

Is there a better choice I am overlooking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question would fit [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

In fact, a [very similar question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/4683) has been asked there, and with a score of 4, seems to have been received well.

As a side note, the question ask you put it here does not show much prior research, and is somewhat open-ended. Adding any processes you already know might help it to be received better. You could ask your barber, the next time you see them - even if they say "we have no such process", that *is* prior research.

I think your question here is a duplicate of the one I linked - but you could ask other ones inquiring how, for example, hair dye or conditioner would influence a given process.