# Where do I go to figure out in which Stack Exchange site I can post my question?

Tags: support

Where do I go to figure out in which Stack Exchange site I can post my question?

(It took me quite a while to find this and I had to go out to DuckDuckGo. Hopefully, this being here will help people find it inside the Stack Exchange ecosystem.)

Comment: If that helps https://stackexchange.com/digests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the best Stack Exchange site for my question before posting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280847/how-do-i-determine-the-best-stack-exchange-site-for-my-question-before-posting)

Comment: Yes! I think there is enough information here to create an answer that is better than those on either of the two questions mentioned above. On which question should I put the new answer with the summary of everything learned?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using a regular search engine, one can search via
https://stackexchange.com/search and see on which SE site(s) relevant posts ended up.

Answer (score 0):

On https://stackexhange.com/sites there are several lists of sites, one showing all, and lists by site categories.

You might also find the list of sites by clicking on [image: Stack Exchange button] button at the toolbar shown on every site.

Another option is to use the Stack Exchange global search by typing your question in the search box in the toolbar at https://stackexhange.com. There are some known issues, so if you don't find something helpful, you might want to try using Google. You might include `site:stackexchange.com` to only include results from sites using the stackexchange.com domain.  You might also like to try the following domains:

- site:askubuntu.com
- site:mathoverflow.net
- site:serverfault.com
- site:superuser.com
- site:stackoverflow.com

Another option is to ask for a site recommendation. Tag your question with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

Comment: Re "`site:`": For other search engines which don't support it, e.g. [DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo), the automatic text added to the HTML <title> tag with the (official) site name ***can be used instead:*** `"Ask Ubuntu"`, `"Stack Overflow"`, `"Super User"`, `"Server Fault"`, `"MathOverflow"`, etc. (I am not sure if the quotes have any effect or not). It is not 100% reliable, but it is usually a good enough qualifier.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum But `site:` _does_ work on DuckDuckGo, at least according to [their help page](https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/syntax/). (Still a super useful tip though)

Answer (score -2):

Try the [list of StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

Be sure to check out the site's Tour and Help Center before posting to make sure your question is on-topic. You will find them by clicking on the circled question mark on the right side of the top bar on the page or in the colored section at the bottom of the page.

See them here when you click on the top bar:
[image]

See them here in the top-left corner of this screengrab:
[image]

(They're also accessible from the top bar- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG6C3.png))